# update new android apps in third party sites

Tags: android

i am developing android apps ,in this apps i am update in android market.

any third party websites update in this new apps thanks in advance please forward some suggestion

Comment: ya i am also facing the same !! third-party websites are not updating the information of my application whenever i release the latest build of my application to the android market

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. And don't add that this is urgent, we don't care.

Comment: He is asking, how to update his apps details, in 3rd party sites like appbrain (that took details from Market once and forget to recrawl) ?

Comment: 3rd party sites like androidpit not in android market

Answer (score 1, accepted):

androidpit and appslib  third party sites of android apps